# PHP not updating

Tags: php, centos

I've currently got 5.2.10 on my centos 5.5 server.

I downloaded 5.2.17 archive, ./configure, ./make and ./make install

The installation completed successfully, with no errors but php -v still shows 5.2.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing packages from source by hand is frowned upon for this reason. It *WILL* make a mess out of your system.

- Files might not install where they are expected (such as you found out)
- You will have potential conflicts if old files didnt get replaced in the new version try to load into the new version (like modules)
- Anything that depends on php expecting a certain version will not get the version it expects and might not work
- Files will be installed to the system but wont ever be able to be cleaned up as they arent being tracked by the RPM system
- When you go to install additional modules for php you will also have to build those for hand as the ones in the RPM repos youre using are for a different version

In other words, do not do that. It is bad.

If you cant find at least a SRPM somewhere that you can rebuild (which I was able to by the way), take the spec file from the closest version you can find and version bump it to the one you want.

Comment: You were right, i removed 5.2.10. Then found an rpm for 5.2.17 and it's installed correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

Try(by default php install in /usr/local/):

```
/usr/local/bin/php -v
```

Comment: That one is 5.2.17, where do i change the path?

Comment: see /etc/profile file